# When does Python actually make the request to a server?

Tags: python, oop, python-requests

This is a bit of a basic, general question but, if I am making a request to a server, at what stage in the code's execution does Python actually query the given URL.

```
import requests
import json

def do_something(results):
    print(results)

params = {"*****": "*****"}
url = "*******.com"

data = requests.get(URL, params=params)
results = comments_data.json()

do_something(results)
```

So for example in the above code, will Python make the request to the server as soon as the `data` object is created, when I convert the response to `json`, or is it when I do something with it later on (in this case print them) that Python actually makes the request?

Comment: here: `requests.get(URL, params=params)`

Comment: Technically, it makes the request *before* `data` is created, because `data` encapsulates the *response*, not the request. The request is not delayed until you actually try to use `data` in a way that requires the data.

Answer (score 1):

It queries the server when you call the `get` or `post` methods of the `requests` module.

So, in your case, it queries the server with line: `data = requests.get(URL, params=params)`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for the quick response